# JSoup does not parse elements

Tags: java, jsoup

I`m trying to get the text between the **"" (info.net, test.com etc)** of below list with jsoup and add them to an arraylist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<supported-filehosts>
<host url="info.net"/>
<host url="test.com"/>
<host url="app.to"/>
</supported-filehosts>
```

Seems easy but I can`t get it right with below code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HOSTS);
Elements links = doc.select("host[url]");

for (Element link : links) {
    hostUrls.add(link.text());
}
```

Could somebody have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `attribute` from each tag:

```
hostUrls.add(link.attr("url"));
```

Example code:

```
public class Main { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        final String HOSTS = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+
            "<supported-filehosts>"+
            "<host url=\"info.net\"/>"+
            "<host url=\"test.com\"/>"+
            "<host url=\"app.to\"/>"+
            "</supported-filehosts>";
        List<String> hostUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HOSTS);
        Elements links = doc.select("host[url]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            hostUrls.add(link.attr("url"));
        }
        System.out.println(hostUrls.toString());
    }   
}
```

Output:

> [info.net, test.com, app.to]

Comment: Hi TDG, thx for the reply but unfortunatly hostUrls is still empty

Comment: Weird, I now give the link to parse directly (Document doc = Jsoup.parse("http://test.org/filehosts.xml"); still nothing

Comment: Whare are your data located? File? Internet?

Comment: And how do you apply data to `HOSTS`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126933/discussion-between-tdg-and-simon).